# Is there a registry flag to turn down the fluent design blur effect or the acrylic glass effect but not entirely disable it?

Tags: windows-10

Anyone familiar with Windows 10 Fluent Design, Microsoft introduced acrylic effect in version 1803 and everyone who likes to use modern UI applications knows that effects like these bring joy to UX when it comes to UI.

Now lets get to the point.

As much as I like the acrylic effect, I would like to change it's strenght a bit down.
It's because I made a "special" wallpaper for my desktop in which I've added a gradient at the bottom with a height of 40 pixels (which is the same height of the taskbar) and this way I can have a nice looking gradient taskbar color.

The issue is that the most of the details from the color is lost due to the strength of the effect.

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

If you compare the picture above and below, you'd see that the picture below preserves more details and has more color to it as more light can pass through.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need a Theme editor.

Comment: @vssher I personally don't like installing custom themes and patchers, I do think there is a flag inside registry or maybe a executable "crack" to make these effects less obvious. 

I should also note that I installed a theme once and had to reinstall the OS because a certain DLL was corrupted and no backup was made which older programs like "SkinPacks" used to create in C drive.

Comment: I was going to post to you a free Theme creator found at MS, but OpenSource and available at GitHub https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/fluent-xaml-theme-editor/9n2xd3q8x57c?activetab=pivot:overviewtab  I think that, unless you can tweak the color by themselves, like we used to do, they are built into the Themes.

Comment: This may help ... _modify the Registry to change color only on the taskbar on Windows 10_ ... https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-color-only-taskbar-windows-10